# jquery validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am adding the dynamic text boxes when click the add link. I want to do the remote validation for dynamic text boxes.

Please see the code below:

```
<input type="text" name="test" id="test1" />

click on add button 

var sc ="<td><input type = 'text' name ='test'  id ='test"+(textid+1)+"'/></td>
document.getElementById("row1-"+textid).innerHTML=sc;
```

Creating the 4 text fields in same way.

I am validating this text fields using jQuery like

```
$("#testSearchForm").validate({
    rules: {
    "test": {
    required:true,
    remote: "chkvalue.action"
}
```

Required validation is working fine but remote method validation is not working.  Can anyone make a suggestion?

Comment: by 'remote validation', do you mean you want to send the values to a server, and have the server response tell if the values are valid?

Comment: Please edit your question to include more details about what you're trying to do and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

- The serverside resource is called via $.ajax (XMLHttpRequest) and gets a key/value pair, corresponding to the name of the validated element and its value as a GET parameter. ***The response is evaluated as JSON and must be true for valid elements, and can be any false, undefined or null for invalid elements***, using the default message; or a string, eg. "That name is already taken, try peter123 instead" to display as the error message.

Hope this information helpfull ...